# Setting Fixed Axis

Tags: plotting, image3d

Is it possible to prevent the values of axis of a 3D plot from moving?

If I run this code:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{x + a, y + a, x + y + a}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], {a, 0, 5}]
```

my axis start to change their values. I would want the graph to move, not the values from the axis. I would prefer to see the fixed point  `O [0,0,0]` (the center of the system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{x + a, y + a, x + y + a}, {x, -3,  3}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-10, 10}}], {a, 0,  5}]
```

[image]

Or, use `PlotRange -> {{-2, 8}, {-2, 8}, {-5, 10}}`.

See also: [Animate >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html)

> Fix PlotRange to stop animations from jiggling.

Comment: @Abbey, they are _the  ranges of  `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates to include in a plot_.  See the documentation page [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html)

Comment: I've just figured that out.